# MySQL INSERT INTO syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following structure

```
user_id int(11)
right   int(11)
group_id int(11)
value   tinyint(1)
```

And 3 queries

```
INSERT INTO  user_rights (`user_id`,`right`,`group_id`,`value`)
VALUES ( '42',  '160',  '1',  '1' );

INSERT INTO  user_rights ('user_id','right','group_id','value')
VALUES ( '42',  '160',  '1',  '1' );

INSERT INTO  user_rights (user_id,right,group_id,value)
VALUES ( '42',  '160',  '1',  '1' );
```

Explain me WHYYYY only the first works????

I have all my life used the third one!

Comment: The second should never work...

Comment: Use the word "permissions", it will be correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`RIGHT` is a [mySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). It will work only when wrapped in backticks.

When you're not using reserved words, it will work without the backticks, as well.

The second way will never work because quotes are used to quote strings, but never database, table or column identifiers.

Comment: thanks, but ... this is an stupidity, why not ' and ` ?? ... nevermind, thanks

Comment: @Row no problem. There are good reasons for this distinction - one is for objects like column and table names, the other for strings. But I agree mySQL's error messages are a bit cryptic in this regard

Answer (score 0):

second one will not work also since "Right" is a reserved keyword for mysql http://drupal.org/node/141051 it will also not work if you want to work that query you have to use  ` for right